# stuck at implementing button

Tags: android

Im very new to java (mainly duel with embedded only)

Im writing a simple android program that passes a value of editText input to another editText by a click of a button. However every-time I hit the button my program crashes. would like anybody comments :)

This is my main:

```
package Mushroom.Pickers.Note;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
//import android.widget.Button;
//import android.widget.TableLayout;

public class Mushy extends Activity {
//private TableLayout layout;
//private Button button;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);      
}   

public void Compute_data(View view) {//Function to perform on click
     //Perform calculation      
     int Hours;
     EditText start_time = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText26) ;
     Hours = Integer.parseInt(start_time.getText().toString());     

     EditText test_time = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText43);
     test_time.setText(Hours);

 }  
}
```

and in my xml:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_width="134px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="Calculate"
        android:onClick="Compute_data" 
        android:textColor="#1e90ff" />
</TableRow>
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText26"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:width="350px" />

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText43"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:width="350px" />
```

The layout appears fine, just the matter of crashing when the button is clicked :(

P/S: here is the logcat:

```
12-19 03:03:02.106: W/ResourceType(667): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000004
12-19 03:03:02.106: D/AndroidRuntime(667): Shutting down VM
12-19 03:03:02.106: W/dalvikvm(667): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
12-19 03:03:02.275: E/AndroidRuntime(667): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-19 03:03:02.275: E/AndroidRuntime(667): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
12-19 03:03:02.275: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
12-19 03:03:02.275: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
12-19 03:03:02.275: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
12-19 03:03:02.275: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-19 03:03:02.275: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-19 03:03:02.275: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-19 03:03:02.275: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-19 03:03:02.275: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-19 03:03:02.275: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-19 03:03:02.275: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-19 03:03:02.275: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-19 03:03:02.275: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-19 03:03:02.275: E/AndroidRuntime(667): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-19 03:03:02.275: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-19 03:03:02.275: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-19 03:03:02.275: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3034)
12-19 03:03:02.275: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  ... 11 more
12-19 03:03:02.275: E/AndroidRuntime(667): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x4
12-19 03:03:02.275: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:247)
12-19 03:03:02.275: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3428)
12-19 03:03:02.275: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  at Mushroom.Pickers.Note.Mushy.Compute_data(Mushy.java:29)
12-19 03:03:02.275: E/AndroidRuntime(667):  ... 14 more
12-19 03:03:02.475: D/dalvikvm(667): GC_CONCURRENT freed 230K, 4% free 10426K/10759K, paused 6ms+14ms
```

Comment: can you please post your logcat?

Comment: sorry how can i actually post it here, its in a table i think

Comment: @user1105087: just copy the logcat as it is(from its table) and simply paste it here.you don't need to modify anything to get it in format.

Comment: i posted the part when it starts to give warnings (then errors) up in the question

Comment: thanks aniway Hiral, members of this website are really helpful, i think i shud be around for a while :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem:**

`test_time.setText(value)` have overridden methods of both `int` and `String` parameters.

- `int` parameter indicate that you will pass `String` resource id. (i.e
  R.string.any_string)
- `String` parameter indicate that you will pass `String`.

you were passing Hours as int not as String.

**Solution:**

you will convet int to String to set as text of any View (i.e `Button`, `TextView`, `EditText`)
Modify your code as below:

```
public void Compute_data(View view) {
     //....
     //here is rest of your code
     EditText test_time = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText43);
     test_time.setText(String.valueOf(Hours));//<<<------consider this change
}
```

Comment: this helps, thanks a lot man. Btw how can i change my usernam, this userxxx sucks lolzz

Comment: @MaxiVu click your name on the top. On your profile, on the top _unanswered_ button there is an _Edit_ button. Click it to edit your profile.

Comment: @gideon: sounds he had changed his name from userXXXXX to MaxiVu

Comment: @adil ah! lol didn't see the first comment! Was reviewing too many posts =P

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling method compute_data() anywhere in onCreate() and even if you would call it,it would not be bounded to button click.and it would give you error when you would pass view to it as you haven't taken button there.instead try this:

```
public class Mushy extends Activity {

   Button button;
   EditText start_time;
   EditText test_time;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button1); 
      start_time = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText26) ;
      test_time = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText43);

      button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

          @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0){

                compute_data();
          }
      });    
  }   

  public void compute_data() {     

     //Perform calculation      

      test_time.setText(start_time.getText().toString()); // puts value of 1st EditText into 2nd
  }  
}
```

Comment: actually i did included in the xml script of the button  android:onClick="Compute_data"

Comment: @Maxi Vu: well,that is also a way!

Comment: matter of curious, what is the way to output a decimal number (float) into the edittext

Comment: you cannot put anything except string in EditText.but you can use this as a hack: float floatValue=2.5;editText.setText(floatValue+"");

Comment: so with the edittext input format as decimalnumber, how can we output anything into the edittext

Comment: just need to convert your "anything" to string object by adding "" to it.